# Unable to render the HTML output on a Page

Tags: asp.net, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to build SPGridView on aspx.cs

Below is the code

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<SharePoint:SPGridView runat=\"server\" ID=\"spgridview\" AutoGenerateColumns=\"false\" AllowPaging=\"true\" AllowSorting=\"true\" Visible=\"true\">\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Columns>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<asp:TemplateField>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<ItemTemplate>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<asp:Label ID=\"lblNo\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"First\"/>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("</ItemTemplate>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("</asp:TemplateField>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<asp:TemplateField>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<ItemTemplate>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("<asp:Label ID=\"lblName\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"Janaki\"/>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("</ItemTemplate>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("</asp:TemplateField>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("</Columns>\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("</SharePoint:SPGridView>\n");
```

I tried `Response.Write(sb.ToString());`, There is nothing on the page. How can I get this working. Maybe I am missing something..Please let me know.

Comment: Are you expecting it to execute the server side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically render controls this way; this is not supported, and will render as plain HTML.  You have to have them statically defined on the page, or load them by adding them to the controls collection or a parent control.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your string builder is a Server Side control.  This means that if you try to write it out when rendering the page, you will get nothing at best or get an error at worst since the browser has no idea what a .NET control is.

If you want to add controls from the code behind you will need to use `Page.Form.Controls.Add()` or something similar to do it.

Based on your code it seems like you could just include the contents of your string builder in the aspx page and set `Visible` to `false` or `true` depending on your needs.